# Does anyone know to upgrade a VB.net 2.0 project to 3.0 in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0, frameworks

Yeah folks i need to upgrade from .net **2.0** to **3.0 framework**, for a **VB.net** project.

I have done this upgradation for a C#.net project in VS 2010, but I dont c the option, for it in the properties submenu of the Project Menu.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the project and choose properties and then select the Compile tab (vertical tab).

At the bottom of the Project > Compile tab you will find an Advanced Compile Options… button.

In this dialog called the Advanced Compiler Settings is where you will find how to change the Target Framework version for Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

Project properties > Tab Compile > Button Advanced Compile Options > Combo Target Framework

Answer (score 1):

Project Menu
 Properties

Select Compile
At the bottom click Advanced Compile Options
Target framework at the bottom.